# Camel/Spring not recognizing correct overloaded method

Tags: java, apache-camel, spring-camel

I am using Apache Camel 2.16.1. I have a class A with overloaded methods:

```
doThing(String, String, String)
doThing(String, String, int)
```

I have some Camel code in Spring DSL:

```
<setProperty>
    <method method="doThing(${body}, 'blah', 10)" ref="A"/>
</setProperty>
```

I keep getting an ambiguous method exception when it seems like it should very clearly resolve to the second "String, String, int" method. If I wanted the first one, the call would have been "doThing('blah', 'blah', '10')". How do I fix this without renaming the method? I've tried things like the following with no success:

```
<setProperty>
    <method method="doThing(${body}, 'blah', int 10)" ref="A"/>
</setProperty>

<setProperty>
    <method method="doThing(${body}, 'blah', '10')" ref="A"/>
</setProperty>

<setProperty>
    <method method="doThing(${body}, 'blah', String '10')" ref="A"/>
</setProperty>
```

Comment: I tried something similar with Java DSL in the latest  Camel 2.22.0  and it works. Can you update your Camel dependencies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comments this works in newer Camel releases since the [BeanInfo class](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/camel-core/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/component/bean/BeanInfo.java) has been improved to choose the best method by using parameter types.

With Camel 2.17 it already works

However, for older versions I assume this is not possible because the [Bean Binding docs](http://camel.apache.org/bean-binding.html) say

> Camel currently only supports either specifying parameter binding or type per parameter in the method name option. You cannot specify both at the same time

Comment: Ahh okay, I'll have to see about updating then. Thanks!